# How to share the domain models between two different projects using different .NET version

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, architecture, microservices

I have a new ASP.NET core Web API application based on .NET 6 which shares the domain models with the Sitecore ASP.NET MVC application using .NET Framework 4.7.2 (legacy code). I want them to communicate with each other via Web API and the same models should be used for that. We wanted to create a new nuget package but unfortunately  because of different .NET versions this is not compatible.
Is there any way to not duplicate the models in both project but extract them somehow and reuse in both?

Comment: @marc_s as you were first to solve my problem please add it as an answer and I will mark it as the solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - create a class library targetting ".NET Standard 2.0" which contains your domain model classes.

It can be used in both .NET 4.7.2, as well as .NET 6 projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Create `Class Library (.NET Standard 2.0)` and put your models.

then reference 2 project to this class library.